# Full Trackpad Features on Ubuntu Laptop

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad

I recently scrubbed my Windows 8 entirely from my Toshiba Satellite E55-A5114 and put Ubuntu 14.04 on it. So far its much better (of course!)

However there are a few nuances that I am trying to reconcile. One of them is my trackpad.

I would really like the ability to do my middle-click by using 3 fingers on my pad, as well as go back by a 3 finger swipe, etc.

Is there any application/driver out there that will give these modern trackpad features to Ubuntu?

My specific version `3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

I use touchpad indicator, though all I want to do is turn it off when there's a mouse plugged in. There is a setting though that should let you set it to three fingers to do a middle click that. On my system I installed it thus:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

THere's a page about it here: 
http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/automatically-disable-touchpad-when-mouse-is-connected-ubuntu/

Comment: How can this answer the question regarding touchpad gestures?

Comment: It doesn't, but it answers the question about enabling three-finger tap as middle-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get 3-finger tap as a middle-click by running in terminal

```
synclient TapButton2=3
```

To make it permanent set it up as an "Automatically started application".